# How to bind selectedItem from different listboxes to one textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

I am very new to WPF and I got stuck with a binding problem.

I have 3 listboxes that I want to bind to one textbox. In listbox1 I have the name "John Doe", in listbox2 "Brian Warner" and in listbox3 "Anne Brown".

When I click on "John Doe" it shows "John Doe" in the textbox and I can change his name because I have this in my xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="Name" Text="{Binding ElementName=listbox1, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"/>
```

Now I want to change the value of the same Textbox to "Brian Warner" when I select the item it in Listbox2 and change the same Textbox to "Anne Brown" when I select her name in Listbox3. 
I also want to be able to edit their name and have it updated in the listbox.

I think I need to find a way to change the binding ElementName from Listbox1 to Listbox2, to listbox3 each time I select and item in the listbox.

How do I do this? I'm very green and I can't find any examples of how to do this. I wish I could provide some more code but I have no idea where to start. Thanks for your help.

UPDATE

I managed to get the desired values from the 3 listboxes in the dedicated textboxes by using the

```
SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged"
```

in the xaml for each textbox.

```
private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb_firstName.Text = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Person).FirstName;
            tb_lastName.Text = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Person).LastName;
            tb_occupation.Text = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Person).Occupation;
            tb_characteristics.Text = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Person).Characteristics;
            tb_email.Text = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Person).Email;
            tb_phoneNr.Text = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Person).PhoneNr;
            tb_moreInfo.Text = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Person).MoreInfo;
            tb_group.Text = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Person).Group;
       }
```

but when I try to change value in the textbox, it doesn't update in the listbox. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can handle this kind of binding in code behind etc etc. But, i would have implement way easier solution: Just create 3 Textboxes in the same layout and style (or not), each one is binded to a specific listbox, and when you raise the event of a listbox's onItemSelected, just show the relevant textbox and collapse the other. Vuala! without any Binding handling that can cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be

1- define a variable which saves the listbox ref
2- use OnItemSelectionChange event for all three 
3- update the flag to indicate which control event is called
4- change the value of text box from each event
5- when value is changed in textbox, use flag to change that value in listbox.

It is not logical to bind a text box with three list boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a single edit field (a `TextBox`) which you would like to use to display and edit the `Name` property of a data object selected in a `ListBox`. There are multiple such `ListBox` objects, and the user should be able to edit the data object that is selected in the `ListBox` that was most recently used.

As it turns out, this isn't an entirely trivial thing to do. I agree with Ben Cohen's reply, in that one approach is to show and hide *different* `TextBox` instances as the focus is changed. A related but different approach is to have just a single `TextBox` and update its `Binding` property on changes in focus.

But it's more complicated than that, because when the user selects an item in a `ListBox`, the `ListBox` itself isn't the object that receives focus. It's the `ListBoxItem` in the `ListBox` that does. There doesn't seem to be a convenient way to access in XAML the `ListBoxItem` that's selected. But even if you could, there's another problem…

In addition, you can't simply bind the visibility of each `TextBox` to the focused state (or a suitable proxy), because as soon as the user actually clicks in the `TextBox`, the `ListBox`/its proxy loses focus.

Anyway, having fiddled with the problem a bit (frankly, probably more than I should have, but hey…I'm learning something new here too :) ), I came up with a code example that I think does exactly what you've asked for here (which I hope is in turn what you want :) ):

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO30283586BindOnFocus.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO30283586BindOnFocus"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate1" DataType="{x:Type local:A}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibilityConverter1"/>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
      <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataTemplate1}"/>
      <Setter Property="Tag">
        <Setter.Value>
          <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="listBoxItem_Focus"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox1"
             Grid.Row="0">
      <ListBox.Items>
        <local:A Name="John"/>
      </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox2"
             Grid.Row="1">
      <ListBox.Items>
        <local:A Name="Jacob"/>
      </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox3"
             Grid.Row="2">
      <ListBox.Items>
        <local:A Name="Jingleheimer"/>
      </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedItem.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Visibility="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=Tag, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter1}}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox2, Path=SelectedItem.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Visibility="{Binding ElementName=listBox2, Path=Tag, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter1}}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox3, Path=SelectedItem.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Visibility="{Binding ElementName=listBox3, Path=Tag, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter1}}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listBoxItem_Focus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox[] listBoxes = { listBox1, listBox2, listBox3 };
        ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;
        ListBox listBoxParent = GetParent<ListBox>(item);

        foreach (ListBox listBox in listBoxes)
        {
            listBox.Tag = object.ReferenceEquals(listBoxParent, listBox);
        }
    }

    private static T GetParent<T>(DependencyObject o) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        while (o != null && !(o is T))
        {
            o = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(o);
        }

        return (T)o;
    }
}

class A : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Name", typeof(string), typeof(A));

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }
}

class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool))
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

There's a little bit of code-behind to deal with issues I wasn't able to address in the markup. In particular, the code-behind includes an event handler that is triggered any time a `ListBoxItem` receives focus. When this happens, the event handler updates the `Tag` property of each `ListBox`, such that the one in which the `ListBoxItem` is contained is set to `true`, while the other two are set to `false`.

In this way, I use the `Tag` property as a proxy for the `IsFocused` property of the `ListBoxItem`, allowing my `TextBox` elements to have their `Visibility` properties bound to that. Note that I only set the `Tag` when focus is *received*. This way, the visibility remains set, even when the focus is lost as the user selects the `TextBox` element.

When you run this program, each `ListBox` is initialized with just one item. When you select an item, it becomes displayed in a `TextBox` to the right. Different `TextBox` elements are shown and hidden as focus changes between the three `ListBox` elements and their items, but to the user it just looks like a single `TextBox` is being updated to reflect the current selection.

If you edit the text in the `TextBox`, the linked item's `Name` property is updated as you do. This change is of course reflected in the display in the `ListBox`.

I can't promise you that this is the *best* way to do this. But it does work. My biggest complaint about it is the hijacking of the `Tag` property. But fact is, as long as you aren't using the property for anything else, it's probably fine to use it for this purpose.

I am actually hoping some real WPF expert will come along and tell me I'm a dummy and there's a much better way to accomplish this. But in the meantime, it's my hope that the above will suit your need adequately. :)

I mentioned above that an alternative would be to update the `Binding` for a single `TextBox` element. I haven't shown the code for that, but it wouldn't be too much different. You'd have only one `TextBox` of course, and the `GotFocus` event handler, instead of messing with the `ListBox.Tag` property, would instead retrieve the actual data object for the `ListBoxItem` sending the event, and configure a new `Binding` object accordingly for the single `TextBox` object.

That approach would avoid the use of the `Tag` property, and might even be slightly more efficient (or might not be…it could go either way). I personally find code to manipulate bindings a bit more complicated than the code above that just sets a property value. But that code is made complicated by the need to walk up the visual tree to find the parent `ListBox`. So maybe it's a wash.

Other than those differences, the code would still be structured much in the same way.